# Get selected row from indexSet

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to retrieve the row selected for deletion in

```
List {
            ...

      }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in ...
```

Deleting an item from my array works by calling

```
posts.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
```

But I would like to retrieve the item from the array first like

```
posts[indexSet.row] ...
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Use indexSet.first!.row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - Get array item with an IndexSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347408/swift-get-array-item-with-an-indexset)